# Re-load form C# anchor not work

Tags: forms, winforms, anchor, reload

I have problem about re-load window form. My source code:

```
private void ReLoadForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Controls.Clear();
        this.InitializeComponent();
        AccountManager_Load(sender, e);
    }
```

But when the form reload was excused, anchor tag not work.

[image: img1]

Comment: What is the problem? Please add the expected and actual result.

Comment: Look like what you need is to reload (or refresh) is the data of your form (the values displayed in your controls) not the controls themselves. You can close the form and open a new one too

Comment: i mean about anchor tag, it be change when i refesh form. My problem is how to keep everything in right locate. My form have size 1280x766, when i choose full screen mode before reload this form, everything can expanse (panel, button,.. keep margin top and right). But when i refesh this form, everything cannot keep style, i mean it's far apart